# Why doesn't the chain fit over the saw bar?

Tags: repair, chainsaw

The chain on a chainsaw I borrowed came off after I used it. I got in back on and it is tight but it will not go around the bar. It starts ok and the chain lock is not on. Why is this happening?

Comment: What caused the chain to come off in the first place? If you pinched the bar, you could have bent the bar and/or damaged the chain.  If the bar/chain is bent/damaged, it will have to be replaced. Is the chain too tight?  Did you add bar and chain oil?

Comment: You should be able to pull up (or down) on the chain near the centr of the bar and get about 1/4" of clearance, it needs a bit of slack. Check the sprocket, I hope you did not strip the teeth off of it!

Comment: Umm ...I didn't strip the teeth. But thanks for the in put. Ill try it again. It's like the sprocket is not turning. One minute it did and then chain came off and then it didn't

Comment: There was plenty of bar oil in it. And I really don't think the kind of cutting I was doing caused the bar the get bent..Ill loosen the chain some and see if that helps but it is like the sprocket is locked up . It doesn't turn when I try to move it with the chain on...tight or loose.

Answer (score 1):

Chains do come off when they heat up if they are not tight.
There are usually 2 bolts on the side of the bar. Break these loose then there will be a screw to tighten /loosen. Loosen the bar move the bar back until the chain will go on.
Once the chain is on tighten the chain and rotate it by hand pulling down in the middle to check for tension. Once the guide no longer clears the bar but there is a little slack tighten the 2 bolts and you are good to go.